# Synchronize ray.remote with a global state actor in Python

Tags: python, ray

I have 2 parallel ray.remote tasks with a global state. The first one sets a new key-value pair in the global state while the second one retrieves this value. Currently, I was only able to do this using a While True loop and constantly checking if the key exists yet. I was wondering if there is a better method to achieve this.

Thanks a lot

```
import ray
import time

ray.init(num_cpus=2)

@ray.remote
class GlobalState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.z = {}

    def set_z(self, key, new_val):
        self.z[key] = new_val

    def get_z(self, key):
        return self.z.get(key, None)


@ray.remote
def task1(global_state):
    while True:
        new_val = ray.get(global_state.get_z.remote("key"))
        if new_val is not None:
            break
    
    return new_val

@ray.remote
def task2(global_state):
    time.sleep(3)
    ray.get(global_state.set_z.remote("key", "value"))
    return 0
    
global_state = GlobalState.remote()

task1 = task1.remote(global_state)
task2 = task2.remote(global_state)

completed_tasks = ray.get([task1, task2])

ray.shutdown()
```